# Disabling Chrome Swipe navigation - Two Finger "back"

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad, multi-touch

Quite recently Chrome has taken up the nasty habit of interpreting errant horizontal scrolling to mean "Go back," which is deeply frustrating. I hit the back button rarely enough that I do not foresee ever needing this feature, and I scroll up and down *all the time* so having that occasionally delete entered text, or leave a video halfway through, is just unnacceptable.

I've found some clear instructions for disabling Swipe Navigation for Chrome on OSX, but nothing for us Ubuntu-kids yet.

Comment: Same question on SuperUser: [How do you disable swipe history navigation?](https://superuser.com/q/840102/443564)

Comment: For Mac users, the same issue has a different solution. See [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/261632/how-to-turn-off-the-back-and-forward-trackpad-gestures-on-a-mac/) or [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21236/how-do-i-disable-chromes-two-finger-back-forward-navigation)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Type `chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation` into the address bar.

Change the state from 'Enabled' to 'Disabled'.

Comment: This flag no longer exists. 54.0.2840.98. Can't find anywhere else to adjust the setting.

Comment: @MatiasVad Still exists on Chrome 58 on my machine. Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: @wjandrea No I'm on MacOS 10.12.5. Using 58.0.3029.110, I saw your comment on the OP

Comment: I confirm this is missing on MacOS for me as well.

Comment: The way to disable now is to execute this command in the terminal: 
`defaults write com.google.Chrome.plist AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE`

Comment: This works on Windows 10 machines as well, on chrome version 79.0.3945.130